# Civicm change UFID to ContactID relationship programatically

Tags: civimember

How can I programatically change the ufid and contact id of CIVICRM?

I know the table `civicrm_uf_match`  holds the matching ids but even if I change that it doesn't matter.  It seems like the ids are put into session but even if I try to change the session variables via:

```
$session =& CRM_Core_Session::singleton( );
$session->set( 'userID' , $myjoomauserid); 
$session->set( 'ufID' $mycivicid);
```

everytime I click renew member its the same member.  I need to be able to change it all on the fly for my custom user interface.  It allows a user to view all civicrm contacts and memberships associated with one email address.  Then the user can edit renew whichever ones they want -- I created this to allow families to be able to edit there kids and for clubs to edit their members.  Any help with how this works would be geatly appretiated.  I used to set the ids in the civicrm_uf_match programatically then log the user out of joomla and log them back in but that doesnt seem to work anymore since the civicrm uprade to 4.6

I am not sure if synchronizeUFMatch as seen in some of the ecode is the route i neeed to look into such as

$ufmatch = self::synchronizeUFMatch($user, $userSystemID, $uniqId, $uf, NULL, $ctype, $isLogin);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does Joomla have an equivalent of [Masquerade](https://www.drupal.org/project/masquerade), where you can temporarily become another user? This can also ([once per request](https://www.drupal.org/node/2514548)) be done programmatically with the masquerade_switch_user and masquerade_switch_back functions.

Comment: Yes and this was eventually how I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Well as usual it turns out to be simple.  I just need to manually make the link in civicrm_uf_match via my program then simply change the session variables via:

require_once 'administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
   require_once 'administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Config.php';
   require_once 'administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/api/v3/UFMatch.php';
   require_once 'administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.settings.php';
   require_once('CRM/Core/DAO.php');

```
$session = CRM_Core_Session::singleton();

$session->set('ufID' , $ufid);     //joomla ID
$session->set('userID' , $userid); //civi contact id
```